# PYTHON - How to create a loop to prompt a specific answer

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop, user-input

Today is my second day of coding, can anyone help me with this?

I'm writing a code to prompt user to answer yes, YES, y, Y or no, NO, n, N. If the user answer with another answer, the system should prompt user to answer again. Below is the current code I wrote.

However, I can't do it, can anyone help? Should I use what kind of loop?

```
print("Please answer the question below in y or n!!")

answer1 = input("Do you want apple?")

answer_yes = "y"
answer_no = "n"


if answer1 == answer_yes:
    print("Here you go!")
elif answer1 == answer_no:
    print("There are apples for you in the fridge!")
else:
    print(input("Do you want apple?"))
```

Comment: You had the correct idea that it needs a loop. A `while` loop will suffice here. If user correctly enters then use `break`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one suggestion:

```
print("Please answer the question below in y or n!!")
answer = ''
answer_yes = ['yes', 'YES', 'y', 'Y']
answer_no = ['no', 'NO', 'n', 'N']

while answer not in answer_yes and answer not in answer_no:
    answer = input("Do you want apple? ")
    if answer in answer_yes:
        print("Here you go!")
    elif answer in answer_no:
        print("There are apples for you in the fridge!")
```

Output:

```
Please answer the question below in y or n!!
Do you want apple? n
There are apples for you in the fridge!
```

Comment: although unnecessary, you could group the conditions together for better read `while (answer not in answer_yes) and (answer not in answer_no) :`

Answer (score 1):

Try a `while True` loop, and `break` when they answer right.